# Software for interactive animation engagement and exchange by making sounds to your phone

Tags: android, video, audio, animation, app

I am looking for an app, whereby, users can look into the phone and make a sound, and in response the phone draws an image of an animal, creature, or person, making that sound.

The picture is animated, and, the sound it makes, is correlated.

It can be longer, or shorter.

It can sound, approximately, similar (or, somehow dragged out or contorted, or, modified, in whatever filter is applied, and presented to the user). There could be a number, of, possible filters.

However, the person, animal, or creature drawn is not arbitrary. It is taken, such, that the user, in some way, attributes, in some, rational, manner, the sound to the creature (based on some criteria, which could be sentiment, experience, and embedding).

These could somehow be input.

The app, must, therefore, have a large database of images that can be animated in parametrized ways programmatically, which, must respond to the user speech to the phone.

There could be two types of app, that work this way.

The one where the animation, produces, the same sound (and an animation).

And the one where the animation produces a response sound (and an animation).

It would be nice if some people were willing to, and could develop, these types of apps.

Is anyone willing to develop these kinds of apps?

Where can I find any?

I, would like to test them, or, find, any of these kinds of apps, and use them (to relax, to, create sentiment, or common sentiment, to stimulate thought, and immerse me into the world's diversity in an interactive manner (including, the diversity, and, soul, thought, and inspiration, that can be brought on by thought and dreaming or dreamingful creativity that can be attributed and imagination).

I think, if, I had, this kind of app, many of my thoughts and many versions of my inner selves, could be, unlocked.

So this app could act as a motivation and ability to dream fantastic stuff and imagine doing things with a fantastic sense of creativity, into one's self.

But I think it for l could be more. It could be a host for creative thought life.

As a standpoint, it could also be a brain magnet for creative video studio artwork development and bringing into being.

Thank you.